# Lenovo mobile broadband

Tags: 3g, broadband, 4g

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my Thinkpad T400, and in addition to traditional ethernet and wifi connections, I would like to enable the mobile broadband, integrated by default on my laptop. The problemthat the system does not detect it and the Lenovo Support Web site, are shown three types of possible cards, installed in my laptop.

Qualcomm Gobi 1000 HS-USB Modem 9202
Qualcomm Gobi 2000 HS-USB Modem 9205
F3507g Ericsson Mobile Broadband Modem

I would like to know if there are drivers for these devices and possibly how to enable the connection.
I look forward to your valuable help.
Thanks in advance.

Alessandro

Comment: The tag 'mobile' relates to using **Ubuntu** on portable devices, such as a smartphone or smaller tablet.

Comment: Do you have (or need) a SIM card?

Answer (score 0):

Running `lsusb` should list, among others, the WWAN adapter in your system.

The two Gobi devices are a bit tricky because they require proprietary firmware to be loaded on startup. You'd need to:

- Install the `gobi-loader` package (later Ubuntu versions have in in the repos, not sure about 12.04)
- Download the Windows driver package and extract the firmware files from it. You need two files named `amss.mbn` and `apps.mbn`, the Gobi 2000 needs a third file named `UQCN.mbn`. Place these files in `/lib/firmware/gobi` on your system.

Note that different versions of these firmware files exist, and the above approach is not guaranteed to work for everyone. (I just managed to get my Gobi 1000 recognized by Linux, but only after disabling and re-enabling it via the hardware switch, and I still can't connect with it.)

I have no experience with the Ericsson F3507g, but I have successfully used another Ericsson WWAN adapter (the F5521gw) with Ubuntu out of the box.